# How can I fix error error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported without downgrading node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Can't figure it out how to solve properly the error described above without downgrading Node.js.

I've tried to downgrade Node.js or using NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider but it's not working, or if it's working, my app is completely different than before.

Below the build log

> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
> at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
> at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
> at module.exports (D:\Achievement Tracker\achievement-tracker\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
> at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\Achievement Tracker\achievement-tracker\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:386:16)
> at D:\Achievement Tracker\achievement-tracker\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:418:10
> at D:\Achievement Tracker\achievement-tracker\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:293:13
> at D:\Achievement Tracker\achievement-tracker\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
> at D:\Achievement Tracker\achievement-tracker\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
> at context.callback (D:\Achievement Tracker\achievement-tracker\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
> at D:\Achievement Tracker\achievement-tracker\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
> opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
> library: 'digital envelope routines',
> reason: 'unsupported',
> code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'

**EDIT:**

Package.json file :
[image]

Comment: show how you applied `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`, when it's not working what errors do you get, or when it's working how is your app completely different than before?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get it to work anymore as I wanted, now i can't even launch correctly the last output page.
I'll edit the question with info that you asked.

Comment: try applying it like `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider; react-scripts build` etc, it should come first, it's an environment option not a param passed

Comment: Should I call it in the same row or somewhere else?

Comment: in the script line, not sure what you mean by row

Comment: I got the following error:
PS D:\Achievement Tracker\achievement-tracker> npm run start

> achievement-tracker@0.0.1 start
> export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider; react-scripts start

'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PS D:\Achievement Tracker\achievement-tracker>

Comment: use `set` instead of `export` on windows

Comment: Now I'm not getting any error, but Debug won't launch. Maybe I have to try again with the downgrade?